# Medical expenses abroad

Tags: eu, austria, health-care

I'm living in Austria and one of my parents needs neurological rehabilitation. The health system in Italy is strongly suffering for the crisis and I would be interested in bringing the member of my family here.

Would Italy / Europe pay for healthcare here?

The question may be also generalized in: is it possible to expatriate for getting health care in one European country?

Comment: Probably not. I will try to elaborate a bit later but while it's often possible to get healthcare while visiting or living abroad through a specific insurance or the EHIC system, it's typically not possible to go abroad specifically to receive care, at least not without *prior* authorization from the relevant insurer/authorities in the country of origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the EHIC serves a different purpose:

> The European Health Insurance Card (or EHIC) is issued free of charge and allows anyone who is insured by or covered by a statutory social security scheme of the EEA countries and Switzerland to receive medical treatment in another member state free or at a reduced cost, **if that treatment becomes necessary during their visit** (for example, due to illness or an accident), **or if they have a chronic pre-existing condition which requires care such as kidney dialysis**.

So no, you won't be able to move *just* to get treatment. However assuming you find a job and settle in a different country you can get health insurance there.